# Error- No resource found that matches the given name (at 'MvxItemTemplate' with value '@layout/itemc')

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross to create PCL.In my Android application,I have created a mvx.mvxListView which has ItemTemplate named itemc.axml.
The file itemc.axml is created in Layout folder but still it gives this error.
Error- No resource found that matches the given name (at 'MvxItemTemplate' with value '@layout/itemc')

Why?

My FirstView.axml file is as follows

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/constD.Droid"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <Button
                             android:text="Show Constituencies"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:id="@+id/button1" />
                    <Mvx.MvxListView
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                             local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Result"
                             local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemc" />
             </LinearLayout>
```

and my itemc.axml file is as follows.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
             <TextView
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:textSize="40dp"
                      local:MvxBind="Text name" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Why it is so?

Comment: @iwayneo sir , Do you know this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Renaming the file itemc.axml to Itemc.axml, see if that works

Comment: For some reason the Mvx item template layout binding requires the xml naming convention i.e. "list_item.axml"

Comment: in my case I had to convert the template name to lower case!   I cannot understand why this restriction.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error when naming in camelCase. renaming to lowercase fixed it.